# Remove single quote from list of strings in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the following. I want to get rid of the single quotes of the strings in the list. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
    name      relations
0   mary      ['andrew', 'jane']
1   jack      ['priscilla', 'mary']
2   jason     ['howard', 'jackie']
```

Expected output

```
    name      relations
0   mary      [andrew, jane]
1   jack      [priscilla, mary]
2   jason     [howard, jackie]
```

Comment: please provide the output of `df.to_dict('list')` the format is currently ambiguous

Comment: I don't think you can do that... a single quote is indicating that, e.g., `'andrew'` is a string whereas `andrew` would be an object

Comment: {'mary': "['andrew', 'jane']",
 'jack': "['priscilla', 'mary]",
 'jason': "['howard', 'jackie']"}    Output from dict(zip(df.name, df.relations))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string becomes an object and displays an error if is not defined. But it should do what you need.

```
df['relations'] = df['relations'].apply(lambda x: list(map(eval,x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The main reason I faced this issue was that my lists were stored as string in the dataframe.

When doing

```
for i, l in enumerate(df[0]):
    print("list",i,"is",type(l))
```

My output is

```
list 0 is <class 'str'>
list 1 is <class 'str'>
list 2 is <class 'str'>
```

When I perform the following code -

```
df['relations'] = df['relations'].apply(eval)
```

I get a list back, and it is now correct.

Output of

```
for i, l in enumerate(df[0]):
    print("list",i,"is",type(l))
```

Give me

```
list 0 is <class 'list'>
list 1 is <class 'list'>
list 2 is <class 'list'>
```

Doing a df again would essentially get what I wanted -> without the single quote in the list

```
name          relations
0   mary      [andrew, jane]
1   jack      [priscilla, mary]
2   jason     [howard, jackie]
```